# VBA - How to save a file after button click in object IE (File URL unknown)

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, savefiledialog

unfortunately I couldn't find any proper solutions for my problem.

I want to download files from a website, that requires me to set some settings to specify what exactly I want to download and then click a button, that will give me the "Save As" dialogue in my browser.

So far I've managed to set the settings and click the button in VBA via InternetExplorer.Application and navigating through the source code by Elements and Tags. The exact problem is now: how can I save the file?
The file URL is (at least for me and my VBA skills) unknown.
The "SendKeys-Way" (not sure if it even would work, since the Save-As-dialogue is one of those security things) is not what I want to use, since the code will run automated and the downloads won't be controlled for days.

I've had two ideas to make this work:
1.) Find a way to activate "AutoSave" in InternetExplorer.Application (which I couldn't find yet).
2.) Somehow find a way to fetch the file URL that will be sent to the Internet Explorer after the click.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Dim sStart As String, sEnd As String
sStart = "01.08.2014"
sEnd = "31.08.2014"

Dim IEApp As Object
Dim IEdoc As Object

Set IEApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IEApp.Visible = False
IEApp.Navigate "https://www.regelleistung.net/ip/action/abrufwert"

Do: Loop Until IEApp.Busy = False
Set IEdoc = IEApp.Document
Do: Loop Until IEdoc.ReadyState = "complete"

Dim myURL As String
Dim Datum As String
Dim text As String
Dim zeile As String
Dim i As Integer, iFiles As Integer
Dim z As Long, lztZeile As Long
iFiles = 0

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    With IEdoc
    .getElementByID("label.von").Value = sStart 
    .getElementByID("label.bis").Value = sEnd
    .getElementByID("uenbId").Value = "jlhPZzcrHoI="

    For i = 0 To .getElementsByTagName("input").Length - 1
        If .getElementsByTagName("input").Item(i).getAttribute("value") = "anzeigen" Then
            .getElementsByTagName("input").Item(i).Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    End With
```

So ... can anyone tell me if one of my two ideas could work and maybe how? Or is there a third way I haven't thought of?
Not knowing the exact file URL seems to make it complicated :/

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what do you mean the url is unknown to your and vba. how can you navigate if the url is unknown? :S

Comment: https://www.regelleistung.net/ip/action/abrufwert
If you check the box at "Herunterladen" and click "anzeigen" you'll directly get the Save File Dialogue. So, the Url of the file to download is unknown (or sent to the explorer in a way I have no idea how to fetch it)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access a link in the website try this

```
For Each link In IEApp.Document.links
   If InStr(link, "http://") > 0 Then ' when http:// tags are found ' use link.innerhtml for html text
         ' send the link  to your download sub routine... 
         download_link(link ) 
   End If
Next link
```

Comment: The problem is, that the download url for the file is not written in the html source code. I expect it to be generated, after the button is clicked and then the link is being sent to my browser, which immediately shows me the Save File Dialogue without showing me the url of the file.